# Parse word docs heroku/s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ms-word

I want to implement a functionality that needs to parse word docs, which will uploaded by user and stored on amazon S3. The application will be on heroku. I tried catdoc but it doesn't parse urls. Can anyone suggest tool that can be used on heroku to parse word documents?

UPDATE
I want to scan an uploaded ms-word(.doc) has particular words and tag them accordingly.

Comment: What kind of information do you want to extract from the documents? Also, what do you mean by "word docs" -- `.doc`, `.docx`, both?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to upload the word document you could take a look at something like the [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

This would allow you to save the file on amazon S3 and simply download it, but you could also extend paperclip and run post-processing on the file. This is slightly more complicated.

Like willglynn says, it would be good to know what parsing you need to do, exactly?